# Unclocked NOR gate SR latch not latching

Tags: digital-logic, switches, logic-gates, latch, pulldown

I am starting to learn computer architecture and decided to try building an SR latch using NOR gates and without a clock (basically copying [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM0DdEaY5sY) video) on a breadboard.

My circuit is pictured, it is using an SN74LS02N IC for the NOR gates and I am powering it using a micro USB wire connected to a 5 V wall plug. I have confirmed that the IC is receiving 5.07 V, so it is within the operating range.

However, when I press the set button (bottom button), the top light initially turns on, but then it turns off, either when I release the button or a few seconds after I release it, with the bottom light turning back on.

I've tested around with the voltmeter and the main issue I have found is that, with the bottom button open, there is still some current flowing across it. With all buttons released, the voltage across the bottom button reads about 4.6-4.7 V instead of the full 5.07 V, with an additional voltage across the bottom pull-down resistor (220 Ω) of about 300-400 mV. The top button and resistor work as expected, with the full voltage dropped across the button when the button is released.

I assume this is the source of the problem, but its solution seems to exceed my abilities right now. I have tried using different buttons, resistor values, ICs, and even breadboards, so I don't think it is a problem with the components.

Does anyone see any problems with what I have done or have suggestions for what I can try next?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Please draw a schematic. With part values such as resistors.

Comment: Always add first a decoupling capacitor (100nF -> 1uF) between pins of supply (Vcc and ground) nearest pins chip !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LEDs are connected to output directly without series resistors.

The high output of an LS TTL gate is very weak so it does not do much damage to the LED or the chip.

But note that the outout goes to a LED and another input pin. The red LED will limit the voltage to about 1.6V, which is below the minimum voltage of 2.0V that the input needs to reliably work.

Comment: The solution to this is to put a resistor in series with each LED.  The 74LS series can sink 16mA, but can only source 400\$\mu\$A.  So if you have the LEDs rigged as "positive on" then you need to use 8.2k\$\Omega\$ resistors and the LEDs will be quite dim.  If you want to use "negative on" then turn the LED's around, connect them to ground, and you can use 220\$\Omega\$ resistors.  They'll be much brighter.

Comment: And also maybe use the 2 other gates as inverters (negative on) so the 2 outputs which are fed back in the latch are not affected by the LEDs.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I connected the LEDs to ground through 220 ohm resistors and it is working great